# drag & drop how to change the content of the draggable element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a list of predefined elements which I store in html files like this

Example

```
Block1 = <div>my Block1</div> saved in block1.html
Block2 = <div>my Block2</div> saved in block2.html
```

Now you should able to drag one of these elements to a div.

In the listlist of these elements "block list" (made with divs) you see a image as a kind of placeholder for this (its unique for each block).

block-list

```
<div class="myblocks" data-parameter1="Block1" data-parameter2="DEF">
<img ...>
</div>
```

my js code is this

```
function getBlockContent(parameter1,parameter2)
{
            $.get(parameter2+'/'+parameter1+'.html', function(data) { html=data; }).done(function(){ console.log(html); }); 
            return html;
      }

$(".myblocks").on('dragstart',function(e) {
     console.log("Drag Started - "+$(this).attr('data-parameter1')+" - "+$(this).attr('data-parameter2'));           
});
    
$('#destinationdiv').on('drop',function(e) {        
   e.preventDefault();  
   e.stopPropagation();
   var newcontent=getContent($(this).attr('data-parameter1'),$(this).attr('data-parameter1'));
   console.log("Drop it - "+$(this).attr('data-parameter1')+" - "+$(this).attr('data-parameter2'));
});

$(".myblocks").on('dragend',function(e) {
            console.log("Drag End - "+$(this).attr('data-parameter1')+" - "+$(this).attr('data-parameter2'));
      });
```

**How I can use the content of the html file to use it and place it to the droppoint, instead the image I've start with dragging from the block-list?**

**At the moment I have the additional problem, that I not receive the parameter inside the drop event - and I don't know why?**
Tried in this way, failed too

```
console.log($(e.target).attr('data-parameter1'));
console.log($(e.originalEvent).attr('data-parameter1'));
```

Hope I could explain what I want to do and what I need to know - thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: I don't see a dragstart or drop event in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/.
There are, however, html5 native events like that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Comment: "$(".myblocks").on('dragstart'" - its already in my code!?